# Homer's been watching TV

Tags: riddle, wordplay

Met up with Homer. He said he had a word in mind, and then told me a riddle.

> Rough, I'm a couple sharing a pie
>
> Smooth, I'm a valley guy from the sky.

What's the word?

Clues:

> The title is important.

A big 'ol hint, read at your own danger.

> The Homer of question is indeed the original greek Homer.

Comment: The answer must be "simpson"?

Comment: Or something about Ilias/Odysee

Comment: Nice eye there @kl78

Comment: @randal'thor Added a hint

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Homer is an ancient Greek. In ancient Greek,

> words that start with a vowel can have "smooth breathing" or "rough breathing". "Rough breathing" indicates an "h" sound. We are looking for two words that are the same except one starts with an "h".

Rough, I'm a couple sharing a pie

> If a couple shares a pie, each person gets **half**.

Smooth, I'm a valley guy from the sky.

> This is **ALF** from the TV show of the same name: an alien who crashes in "The Valley" area of California.

Answer (score 3):

Is the answer

> TV (which is *right there* in the title!)

Rough, I'm a couple sharing a pie

> The letter `T` looks like one half of the Greek letter $\pi$, which could mean a couple sharing a pie.

Smooth, I'm a valley guy from the sky.

> A valley when seen from afar would represent the shape of the letter `V`.

Comment: I had something else in mind!

Comment: I actually really like this, but the answer hinges on the "rough" and "smooth" parts

Answer (score 0):

Could it be:

> the number pi?
>  pi is a number that is named after a greek letter. Homer wrote in Greek.
>  There's the expression "pie in the sky" which would fit both clues